# Why we can't create getter inside build method whereas we can create method?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-lints

On Flutter we can create method inside inside the build method, but why we cant create getter(`get`).

Minimal reproducible snippet

```dart
class A extends StatefulWidget {
  const A({super.key});

  @override
  State<A> createState() => _AState();
}

class _AState extends State<A> {
  int get _foo => 0; // Ok
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int get _bar => 1;  /// invalid
    return Container();
  }
}

class B extends StatelessWidget {
  const B({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int get _bar => 1; /// invalid
    return Container();
  }
}
```

I am using `flutter_lints: ^3.0.0`. Is it possible to create getter inside build method?

Comment: Supposing that you could, how would a consumer of `class A` be able to dereference/invoke the `_bar` getter?

Comment: thanks, I was thinking about using getter on inside the build, the same way use(local function,not good way) method

Comment: @Dai it is not officially discouraged. The official style guide for dart is [effective dart](https://dart.dev/effective-dart) and it does not even mention local functions. That said, while you can create a local function, as far as I know, there is no way to create a local GETTER function, and I'm not sure why since top level GETTER functions and GETTER methods are both allowed.

Comment: @mmcdon20 My mistake, I thought `dcm.dev` was authoritative. Apparently it isn't. Whoops.

Comment: @mmcdon20 C# has a similar restriction: while C# allows local functions, it doesn't allow local properties - the reasoning being that properties cannot be passed around by-reference (whereas functions/methods _can_ be passed-around via a delegate-type (i.e. a function-pointer), also it would result in programs that are harder to read/follow/understand and for very limited gain. I can't think of any compelling reason to want this functionality, but I can think of difficulties and issues that it would introduce.

Answer (score 0):

### Getters can't be declared locally inside a method.

This's because of the intended usage of these getters, it's intended to be **encapsulated** within the instances of the class in which they are declared.

So, Getters are special methods that provide explicit read access to an object's properties. and must be declared on class level not locally inside a method.

actually, this answer should be long to explore some concepts like encapsulation. However, we can ask some questions that explain why not locally.

> **How can the object access its getters if they are nested?**

suppose it can.

> **what if the instance method which the getter is declared within is
> marked as static method not instance?**

object can't even see that static method.

So, it must be declared at class level to perform as supposed.